# use a custom android theme holo color

Tags: java, android, themes

hello I have tried @style/theme and @android:style/theme but none work...... my code is... 
Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/themes" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.UserRegister"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.ForgotPassword"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.SendEmailTransition"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_send_email_transition" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ucapp.uppercrustapp.OrderMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order_menu" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

custom theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="green" parent="@style/_green"/>

<style name="_green" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextgreen</item>

<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxgreen</item>

<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Spinnergreen</item>

<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemgreen</item>

<item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBargreen</item>

<item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewgreen</item>

<item name="android:listViewWhiteStyle">@style/ListViewgreen.White</item>

<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItemgreen</item>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="green_color">#1c810b</color>
 </resources>
```

styles.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
      <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="EditTextgreen" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/green_edit_text_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CheckBoxgreen" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/green_btn_check_holo_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Spinnergreen" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/green_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/green_list_selector_holo_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerDropDownItemgreen" parent="android:Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/green_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ProgressBargreen" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item   name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/green_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
       <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/green_progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
      <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ListViewgreen" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
      <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/green_list_selector_holo_light</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ListViewgreen.White" parent="android:Widget.ListView.White">
      <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/green_list_selector_holo_light</item>
  </style>

     <style    name="SpinnerItemgreen"
parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
      <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
  </style>

     </resources>
```

This custom color theme was made from an online generator. I have tried to look on youtube but no luck. and I have tried to but the images in its folders them change them but I would like to know how to make a custom theme work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `android:theme="@style/green"` in your manifest.